# Copy Pasted content also carries over extra html tags EditorJS

Tags: vue.js, formatting, nuxt.js, editorjs

I'm using EditorJS on my website and I've encountered this issue recently where copying over content from a google doc also pastes the text formatting for that text. On the previous version of EditorJS that I was using on an old website this wasn't an issue. In the underneath pictures you can see the result of copy pasting the same paragraph from a google doc:

Old version of editorJs
[image]

New version of editorjs
[image]

On the previous website I was using this version of the EditorJS and paragraph tool:

```
"@editorjs/paragraph": "^2.8.0",
"@editorjs/editorjs": "^2.19.0",
```

On the current one i'm using this version

```
"@editorjs/editorjs": "^2.27.2",
"@editorjs/paragraph": "^2.10.0",
```

In both cases I'm initializing the editor in the same way with pretty much the same configuration, I've added a few extra tools tools to the new editor, some ad-hoc, some from the recommended plugins.

I've tried downgrading to "@editorjs/editorjs@2.19.0" and "@editorjs/paragraph@2.8.0", thinking that there might be a difference in how code is sanitized between the different version, the result was the same.

I've also noticed that when I pasted this specific paragraph into the editor I get this error

[image]

I was wondering if maybe i'm doing something wrong and if there is any way i can remove the unecessary html code on paste.

Thank you!